# How to set the device name (as friendly name) in Airwatch/Workspace ONE via Rest-API

Tags: rest, vmware-workstation, airwatch

I am looking to change the Device Name and Friendly Name of iOS devices to a different value via the Rest-API. I am able to change the Friendly Name like this:

```
$requestHeaders = @{
   'Accept' = 'application/json'
   'Authorization' = $auth
   'aw-tenant-code' = $wsoApiKey
}
$body = @{
   'DeviceFriendlyName' = $WsoDeviceName
}
$body = ConvertTo-Json $body
$uri = $wsoApiUri + $WsoDevice.Id.Value
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $requestHeaders -Body $body -Method Put
```

But I can't seem to find the correct attribute to change the Device Name, neither in the local API help (at server.local/api/help), nor in vmwares documentation.
Sending a PUT-request to change the DeviceName or DeviceReportedName shows no changes whatsoever. The code for that looked like:

```
$body = @{
    'DeviceName' = $WsoDeviceName
}
```

I am aware of the possibility to set the Friendly Name as Device Name via the web interface. Maybe there is a way to activate that option via API, that I did not find? In this case it would get the job done.

Would be glad, if someone could point me in the right direction.

Best regards

Holewasch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using a custom MDM command. In the example below, I specifically use the `POST /devices/commands` method while searching by a serial number for the device.

```coffee
$MdmCommandXml = [xml]@'
<dict>
  <key>RequestType</key>
  <string>Settings</string>
  <key>Settings</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>DeviceName</key>
      <string></string>
      <key>Item</key>
      <string>DeviceName</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
'@

$Auth = ""
$WsoApiKey = ""

$BaseUrl = "https://as<yourhostnumber>.awmdm.com/API/mdm"
$SerialNumber = ""
$Uri = "${BaseUrl}/devices/commands?command=CustomMdmCommand&searchBy=Serialnumber&id=${SerialNumber}"
$NewDeviceName = "NewDeviceName"

$MdmCommandXml.SelectSingleNode('//key[.="DeviceName"]/following-sibling::*[1]').InnerXml = $NewDeviceName

$RequestHeaders = @{
    'Accept' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = $Auth
    'aw-tenant-code' = $WsoApiKey
 }
 $Body = @{
    'CommandXml' = $MdmCommandXml.OuterXml
 }
 $Body = ConvertTo-Json $Body
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $RequestHeaders -Body $Body -Method Post
```

Comment: I had to modifiy it slightly to get it to work with (my version of) powershell, but otherwise worked like a charm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to implement the above solution, in order to rename device friendly names. See attached script below. When passing your specified uri value, the cmd output is this :

```
'Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.'
```

This suggests that my uri variable is not being populated. I am wondering if access to this functionality has been changed with a recent update to the API?

```
$MdmCommandXml = [xml]@'
<dict>
  <key>RequestType</key>
  <string>Settings</string>
  <key>Settings</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>DeviceName</key>
      <string></string>
      <key>Item</key>
      <string>DeviceName</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
'@
$server = "https://xxxxx.awmdm.com/"
$client_id = "client_id"
$client_secret = "client_secret"
$access_token_url="token_url"
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $client_id
    client_secret = $client_secret
}
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $access_token_url -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
    $response = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
    $oauth_token = [string]$($response.access_token)
} catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $PSItem | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Log "Failed to create OAuth Token for: $env with following ErrorCode: $($ErrorMessage.errorCode) - $($ErrorMessage.message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
$header_v1 = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $oauth_Token;
    "Accept" = "application/json;version=1";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$header_v3 = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $oauth_Token;
    "Accept" = "application/json;version=1";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$WsoApiKey = "WsoApiKey"
$BaseUrl = "https://xxxxx.awmdm.com/API/mdm"
$SerialNumber = "R52N30M3T3P"
$Uri = "${BaseUrl}/devices/commands?command=CustomMdmCommand&searchBy=Serialnumber&id=${SerialNumber}"                                                #$Uri = "${BaseUrl}/devices/commands?command=CustomMdmCommand&searchBy=Serialnumber&id=${SerialNumber}"
$NewDeviceName = "NewDeviceFriendlyName"
$uri = $wsoApiUri + $WsoDevice.Id.Value                
$MdmCommandXml.SelectSingleNode('//key[.="DeviceName"]/following-sibling::*[1]').InnerXml = $NewDeviceName
$test = $MdmCommandXml.SelectSingleNode('//key[.="DeviceName"]/following-sibling::*[1]').InnerXml;
 $Body = @{
    'CommandXml' = $MdmCommandXml.OuterXml
 }
 $Body = ConvertTo-Json $Body


 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$server/api/mdm/devices/search?" -Method Get -Headers $header_v1
 #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $header_v1 -Body $Body -Method Get
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $header_v1 -Body $Body -Method Post
```

Best Regards,

Liam

Comment: It looks like you're combining the script in my answer with the script in the original question, which is causing conflicts. Most notably, you're changing the value of `$uri` to `$uri = $wsoApiUri + $WsoDevice.Id.Value` on line 50, yet `$wsoApiUri` is not being defined in your version of the script you posted. I would suggest using only the code from my answer and not any code from the original question.